# mysql regex to match paths

Tags: mysql

My table has data like

```
/my/path/project1/1.ft2.3
/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/
/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/
/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/test
/my/path/project1/hash3.4.5.6
/my/path/project1/7.8.9
```

My intention is to use a regex to match

```
/my/path/project1/1.ft2.3
/my/path/project1/hash3.4.5.6
/my/path/project1/7.8.9
```

What is a good regex to basically match, given a path -- to match `<path>/<match>/` ?

This one I am using matches all

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE path REGEXP '/my/path/project1/.*';
```

Comment: `^/my/path/project1/[.0-9]+$`

Comment: Modified my question. I have both digits and alphabets to match, unfortunately.

Comment: `^/my/path/project1/[^/]+$`

Comment: Why not use `WHERE path LIKE '/my/path/project1/%'`?

Comment: @DanFromGermany that would match `/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/test`, which he doesn't want to match.

Comment: @jordanm Your second regex looks good to me.  Maybe you can post that as an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: unfortunately jordanm's second regex doesnt return anything.

Comment: @jordanm: Your answer is right. Could you please post this answer so I can accept it as the right one? Thank you for your help. [^/]+/$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will work for your use-case:

```
^/my/path/project1/[^/]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `REGEXP '\/my\/path\/project1\/.*'`:

```
SELECT '/my/path/project1/1.ft2.3' REGEXP '\/my\/path\/project1\/.*' AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

To select values which you've specified - try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT '/my/path/project1/1.ft2.3' AS f
  UNION SELECT '/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/'
  UNION SELECT '/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/'
  UNION SELECT '/my/path/project1/1.2.3/1.2.3.0/test'
  UNION SELECT '/my/path/project1/hash3.4.5.6'
  UNION SELECT '/my/path/project1/7.8.9'
) t
WHERE f REGEXP '\/my\/path\/project1\/(1\.ft2\.3|hash3\.4\.5\.6|7\.8\.9)'
;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------------+
| f                             |
+-------------------------------+
| /my/path/project1/1.ft2.3     |
| /my/path/project1/hash3.4.5.6 |
| /my/path/project1/7.8.9       |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesnt help @vladmir. This matches everything with /my/path/project1.